# How to allow wordpress to write web.config on IIS 7 for pretty url

Tags: iis-7, wordpress, rewrite

It is possible to get pretty url with IIS 7 by hand
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/466/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress/

but wordpress can also do it automatically if it has the right permission.

How to give this permission on IIS 7 ?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you are correct .. adjusting permissions on the IIS server will not make pretty URLs function properly.

When WordPress is implemented on top of the Apache webserver (on any OS), pretty URLs require that the "mod_rewrite" module is enabled on Apache. WordPress will modify the Rewrite rule itself if the `.htaccess` file has proper permissions, which it does by default.

On IIS, pretty URLs will function properly when the URL Rewrite module is enabled, but WordPress does not know how to modify the rewrite rules in the `web.config` file, so it must be done manually. If you really care about the feature, make a request on the wordpress.org forum [features and feedback](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/4) section.

*BTW .. there is a [WordPress StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500/wordpress-answers) site winding it's way through the process at Area51. I invite any WordPress users/admins here to check it out and "commit" if you think it would be helpful. I did!*

Comment: Thanks but I do think I am correct :) there is a IIS wordpress version and on a shared hosting iis server it did it automatically, I'm now using a dedicated server I'm not used to IIS yet to do so.

Comment: You are pretty much alone in that opinion. Perhaps an email to tech support for the shared host asking them to let us in on the secret would clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I manage two wordpress sites.

Site 1 details:

```
WordPress: 3.0.1
PHP: 5.2.13
MySQL: 5.1.47
WebServer: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
```

Here web.config ***is not*** written by WordPress when permalinks changes are saved

Site 2 details:

```
WordPress: 3.0.1
PHP: 5.2.13
MySQL: 5.1.47
WebServer: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

Here web.config ***is*** written by WordPress when permalink changes are saved